# VB.NET sending email in a separate thread

Tags: vb.net, vb.net-2010

I have a main form in vb.net with a button and upon click of that button will show a Windows Dialog which contains another button. On click of the button in the dialog, I have to send an email and close the dialog.

Here's the problem

The email sending takes around 5 to 6 seconds. I need to close the dialog before I send the email. I'm thinking of putting the email sending in a thread. What is the best way to achieve this? Can you please send a sample code? What happens if the thread is running when the dialog was closed?

Also, would it be better to use a backgroundworker instead? I'm not sure if threading is the best way to go about it.

Comment: I've tried to run the email sending as a thread. This solves the responsiveness issue and the dialog gets closed immediately. However, I encounter intermittent errors like these: "Encountered Error(SendEmail) : Error creating window handle". I'm not sure if this is because the thread is declared in the dialog and the dialog was closed before the thread completed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
 Public Class libMail   

  Private WithEvents bw As New BackgroundWorker

    Public Sub BackgW()
        bw.RunWorkerAsync()
    End Sub

    Private Sub BackgroundWorker1_DoWork(sender As Object, e As DoWorkEventArgs) Handles bw.DoWork

        SendMail("Subject", "SendingMail")

    End Sub

      Public Shared Function CheckForInternetConnection() As Boolean


        Try
            Return My.Computer.Network.Ping("www.google.com")
        Catch
            Return False
        End Try

    End Function

    Public Function SendMail(subject As String, msg As String) As String
        Try

            Select Case CheckForInternetConnection()
                Case True

                    Dim smtpServer As New SmtpClient
                    Dim eMail As New MailMessage()
                    smtpServer.UseDefaultCredentials = False
                    smtpServer.Credentials = New System.Net.NetworkCredential("YourMail", "yourPassword")
                    smtpServer.Port = 587
                    smtpServer.EnableSsl = True
                    smtpServer.Host = "smtp.gmail.com"


                    eMail = New MailMessage()
                    eMail.From = New MailAddress("yourMail")
                    eMail.To.Add("MailToSend")
                    eMail.Subject = subject

                    eMail.IsBodyHtml = False
                    eMail.Body = msg
                    smtpServer.Send(eMail)

                    Return "SENT"
            End Select
            Return Nothing
        Catch ex As Exception

            Return Nothing
        End Try

    End Function

   Private Sub BackgroundWorker1_RunWorkerCompleted(sender As Object, e As RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs) Handles bw.RunWorkerCompleted

             'do some work when is over
  End Sub

   End class
```

'call it

```
        Using l As New libMail
            l.BackgW()
            'CLOSE FORM
        End Using
```

Comment: Hi thanks! But in this case I would have to close the form only in BackgroundWorker1_RunWorkerCompleted right? Is it possible to do something like this? Step 1. Call l.BackgW, Step 2. Close the dialog.

Comment: @RaymondWee yes it is